# Meaning of 'rules of order', 'schemes of classification'

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Finally, the general pattern of school organization (by which I mean the relations of pupils to one another and to the teachers) constitutes the school a kind of institution sharply marked off from other social institutions. Call up in imagination the ordinary schoolroom, its time-schedules, **schemes of classification**, of examination and promotion, of **rules of order**, and I think you will grasp what is meant by “pattern of organization.” If
>   then you contrast this scene with what goes on in the family, for example, you will
>   appreciate what is meant by the school being a kind of institution sharply marked
>   off from any other form of social organization. [(Source)](http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys4810/phys4810_fa08/4810_readings/dewey_ch1.html)
>
> Which one of the following is NOT suggested as a possible feature of the
>   ‘general pattern of school organization’?
>   (a) timetables
>   (b) examinations
>   (c) school uniform
>   (d) school rules
>   (e) a set curriculum

I struggle with the abstract notions in the quote, so would someone please explain how to apply them to the choices? What do **rules of order**, **schemes of classification** mean? They sound hazy and vague.

2. Isn't (c) a rule of order, because school uniforms maintain order? (c)'s the right answer. Also, (d) says rules so I think this is why it's wrong.

3. Isn't (e) a scheme of classification? I picked this but this is wrong.

Despite my primitive English, the passage does state (a) and (b), thus they aren't the answers.

Comment: First, do you know what a "school uniform" is?

Comment: Good for you. Care to elaborate?

Comment: What things are *classified* by a curriculum?

Comment: @TRomano Thanks. I apologise if this question sounds too basic, but my English is primitive so please forgive me. A curriculum classifies subjects and topics to be taught and followed by teachers. Please advise how to continue with this?

Comment: Of the possible answers: clothing, school rules, and set curriculum, which one has *least* to do with the "time-schedules, schemes of classification, examination and promotion, and rules of order?"  It is almost impossible to know what schemes of classification refers to; a synonym for it would be "taxonomy". Rule of order relates to procedures.

Answer (score 1):

A "scheme of classification" is a specific way of dividing things into categories. For example, if a linguist said that he is going to classify words by part of speech, putting nouns in one category, verbs in another, adjectives in another, etc, that would be a "scheme of classification". It's not the only possible scheme of classification. We could also divide words by their origins: which came from Latin, which from German, etc.

The most obvious scheme of classification in a school is by grade level, i.e. age. Another is to divide classes by department: arts, sciences, language, etc. The writer may have these or other classifications in mind.

"Rules of order" is not so strictly defined in this context. In general if someone says "rules of order" they mean the rules by which a meeting of a debating or rule-making organization is conducted. Like, "A motion must be seconded before it can be debated" and "a 2/3 majority is required to repeal a decision made previously". But that meaning is not applicable here. I'd guess he simply means the rules that are put in place to maintain order, like "no running in the halls" and "a bell will sound at the beginning of lunch break".

You don't mention what choices (a) and (b) where. I think (d) is pretty clearly wrong, because "school rules" is likely just another way of saying "the school's rules of order".

(e) is debatable as the text doesn't specifically mention curricula, but it's consistent with all the items listed in the text. You ask if it is not a scheme of classification. Well. arguably it IS, and as the question asks for which is NOT suggested, then if (e) IS suggested, it cannot be the right answer.

(c), school uniforms, don't clearly fall under any of the items listed. One could argue that if school rules requires students to wear uniforms, and if the purpose of this rule is to maintain order, then uniforms are included under "rules of order" and so (c) can't be the right answer. If there are different uniforms for different categories of students, like one uniform for grades 1-6 and another for grades 7-9, then this could be part of a scheme of classification. So I'd say that one could argue that uniforms ARE suggested and there is no right answer. But of the choices given, uniforms are least clearly included in any of the concepts mentioned, and so would be the most likely choice.

Comment: Thank you. I included (a, b); I had forgotten them because they are easy to eliminate.